# How to get IE to ignore history.pushState?

Tags: internet-explorer, pushstate

I've implemented pushState/onPopState in a small web app I've created.  The app now throws javascript errors in IE because IE doesn't support these methods.  Is there any way I can do a check like

```
if (method_exists(history.pushState)) { 

    history.pushState(blah, blah, blah);
}
```

So that IE will ignore this part of the app and not throw an error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (typeof history.pushState != 'undefined') { 
    history.pushState(blah, blah, blah);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I all I had to do is if (history.pushState) { ... }.  But I'm not allowed to answer my question within 8 hours so I couldn't clarify :-)  Thanks!